# Chinese Fill in the Blanks and Translation for Two Sentences

Tags: translation

I was wondering if someone could check if the fill in the blanks and the translation for the underlined sentences marked 1 and 2 are correct.

Sentence 1

> 夏天的天气非常热，我朋友还得在外边陪狗玩儿。
> The weather during the summer is extremely hot, my friend still accompanies his dog to go play outside.

Sentence 2

> 狗一回家它们就跳到很高的地方去睡觉。
> As soon as the dog comes home, the cats jumps [sic] to a high place to sleep.

Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the translations are fine, except:

1. In sentence 1, `還得` implies obligation. So it may be better to add 'to have to' in the sentence:

   > The weather during the summer is extremely hot, but my friend still has to accompany his dog to go play outside.
2. An English grammar mistake in sentence 2: 'the cats jump', not 'the cats jumps'.

Comment: do you think the fill in the blanks are all correct, especially the 就 VS 就是 Thanks

Comment: Yes, all seem fine. 不是⋯⋯就是 is a pair, whereas 一⋯⋯就 is another

Answer (score 0):

填空都好了！

I suppose the question is valid:

Dog, Master: Who takes whom for a walk?

Generally speaking, I would say, master takes dog for a walk!

Chinese good, English wanting.

夏天的天气非常热，
The summer weather is scorching (hot),
我朋友还得在外边陪狗玩儿。
but my friend still has to take his dog for a walk/run.

狗一回家它们就跳到很高的地方去睡觉。
As soon as the dog gets back, they, (the cats,) jump up somewhere high (and dogless) to sleep.

"accompanies his dog to go play outside." sounds weird.

Try "takes his dog for a run/walk"